# Liquid slider dots via CSS3 or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made slider dots to be animated and working like a liquid substance on the changing.

It looks like this

[image]

I try to use pure CSS like this:

```css
.intro--slider-dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 70px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro--slider-dots>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #45A36E;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

.intro--slider-dots>li.active,
.intro--slider-dots>li:hover {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.intro--slider-dots>li+li {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.intro--slider-dots>li+li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -26%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #45A36E;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="intro--slider-dots">
  <li class="active" data-index="0"></li>
  <li data-index="1"></li>
  <li data-index="2"></li>
</ul>
```

But I don't know how to shape this like image above. It would be nice to have some nice liquid effect from the left to right or opposite.

Comment: [Check this post](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/) , it has different ways of achieving such an effect (or a similar one)

Comment: Hm... in the general I need to do tricks with rotation and angle of the square. Also with shaddow mix. Nice article, never se it before. Will try this. Thanks!